# Could not find server '+@servername + ' in sys.servers

Tags: sql-server

I am not able to find server name when I pass as parameter to sp_execute (I have added server as linked server). It does get executed when I pass a hardcoded server name.

```
SET @PARMDEFINITION =N'@SOURCE_SERVER_NAME_IN VARCHAR(100), @SOURCE_DB_NAME_IN VARCHAR(100) ,@DESTI_SERVER_NAME_IN VARCHAR(100), @DESTI_DB_NAME_IN VARCHAR(100),
                       @DESTI_STUDENT_COUNT_OUT INT OUTPUT,@SOURCE_STUDENT_COUNT_OUT INT OUTPUT';


SET @SQLSTRING='SELECT @SOURCE_STUDENT_COUNT_OUT=COUNT(*) FROM [@SOURCE_SERVER_NAME_IN].[@SOURCE_DB_NAME_IN].DBO.STUDENT_MST WHERE CONVERT(FLOAT, RANK) <> 0 AND PAID2 =''S'''                 

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLSTRING,@PARMDEFINITION,@SOURCE_SERVER_NAME_IN=@SOURCE_SERVER_NAME,@DESTI_SERVER_NAME_IN=@DESTI_SERVER_NAME,
@SOURCE_DB_NAME_IN=@SOURCE_DB_NAME,@DESTI_DB_NAME_IN=@DESTI_DB_NAME ,
@SOURCE_STUDENT_COUNT_OUT=@SOURCE_STUDENT_COUNT OUTPUT,@DESTI_STUDENT_COUNT_OUT=@DESTI_STUDENT_COUNT OUTPUT;
```

> *Could not find server '+@servername + ' in sys.servers*

Please advise.

Comment: please post the code that has caused this error.

Comment: @Saurabh I've tried to reword your question to make more sense, please do say if I've misinterpreted what you wanted.

Comment: Is the above your actual error message or is `@servername` replaced with actual value that you pass to stored procedure? Where is the actual code of stored procedure? I suspect that you don't use the parameter correctly (as a parameter)

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass server or table names as parameters to `sp_executesql`

You'll have to do it like this

```
SET @SQLSTRING='SELECT @SOURCE_STUDENT_COUNT_OUT=COUNT(*) FROM '
    + quotename(@SOURCE_SERVER_NAME_IN) + '.'
    + quotename(@SOURCE_DB_NAME_IN) 
    + '.DBO.STUDENT_MST WHERE CONVERT(FLOAT, RANK) <> 0 AND PAID2 =''S'''
```